# Could it be that Spark's SaveMode.Append cause to duplicate in the data?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm reading data with Spark from delta-lake to an S3 bucket and doing it with append mode because sometimes I add a partition to an existing directory and don't want to overwrite the existing data. I see some duplication in the data, and I'm wondering if it could somehow be related to the fact that I use append mode.

The use case - I have data partitioned by app and dt:

```
data
 |---dt=2022-01-01
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
 |---dt=2022-01-02
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
     .
     .
     .
```

Sometimes I need to bring new data for another app, in existing dt. For example, to get this result -

```
data
 |---dt=2022-01-01
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
 |   |---app=z
 |   |---app=w
 |---dt=2022-01-02
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
 |   |---app=z
     .
     .
     .
```

So I write `w` and `z` with append mode because I don't want to overwrite `x` and `y`.
The problem is that I see duplication in the `w` and `z` data.
Any idea why? How can I solve this?